# How to restrict access for specific sub-site group user's to root site in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell

In SharePoint 2010 I have root site for e.g.

`http://moss-root//`  under this we have lots of sub-sites like

```
http://moss-root/subsite1
```

`http://moss-root/subsite2` --- I need to restrict this subsite group user's should not access to root site.

We had created separate group for `subsite2` and created `unique permission` for this site.

My problem user's are still able to access root site becoz the user's under the subsite2 group exist on same domain,

How to restrict user's exist in same domain should not access to `root site` but only `subsite2`.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, SharePoint adds "domainusers" or "Everyone" to the "Moss-root visitors"-group. Please check if this is the case in your environment.

Removing this domainusers-group will remove all read permissions on moss-root for everyone. Only users that have been granted permission through another way will be able to access moss-root.

In case you need a group of people to access moss-root and only deny a couple of users access, create an AD group with the people that should have access and add this group to the "moss-root visitors"-group.

Comment: In my case, we have created SharePoint group under that we added domain\users's, now once any user is created with this domain he/she is able to access the root site.

Comment: How to restrict that, any help

Comment: Yes, if they are in the same domain, they will get access through the domain\users - group. You'll have to remove this group from your SharePoint group to deny the access.

Create a new AD group with the people that need access to the root site and add this new group to the visitors SharePoint group.
As far as I know, there is no way to deny access to a specific group inside a site collection. This is possible on Web Application level (at least in SP2013, I cannot test in SP2010 as I do not have an environment available), but that means they won't have access to the subsite either.